# Excel: adapt column computation to length of data set

Tags: excel

I.e. the first column has 100 entries and the second also 100, because it uses the corresponding data from the first column

When an entry is added in the first column, the second column should do the corresponding computation on the new entry.

I do not want to write the formula in the whole second column, because it is a very expensive computation. The second column should adapt itself to the length of the first column.

Comment: Select your filled cells in columns 1 and 2 -> Insert -> Table.  Then when you add data to column 1, the table will update column 2 to match.

Comment: You need to tell us how the second column is using **`corresponding data`** from first column so that we can understand what you are trying to achieve